# Inject builder.Configuration into a service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

The questions relate to ASP.Net Core (.Net 7, fwtw) and *Minimal API*...

I have a rather basic project that looks like this:

NOTE: [snipped] appears below simply to occlude stuff that shouldn't matter (but may be helpful as you read). T and X indicate type names (similar to but not exactly ).

**program.cs**

```
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Configuration.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("[snipped].json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("[snipped].json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

builder.Logging.AddConsole();
builder.Logging.AddApplicationInsights(ApplicationInsightConnectionString);

builder.Services.AddLogging();
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(builder.Configuration);

[snipped]

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

[snipped]

app.MapPost("/[snipped]",
    async (HttpContext context, T, IXService service, CancellationToken cancel) => await new XDispatch(context, builder.Configuration, logger).Create(T, service, cancel))
    .Accepts<T>("application/json")
    .Produces<string>(contentType: "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
```

NOTE: XDispatch is the service constructor. Handle is the route handler (off that service).

0. I'm new to stackoverflow. Should I break this into 4 distinct questions? (pardon my ignorance if  there is too much "ask" here.)
1. Is the builder.Logging.Add[Logging|ApplicationInsights] stuff even remotely correct? (i have appropriate config in the appsettings.json and elsewhere as described by Microsoft. i do not want to use a 3rd party log provider like Serilog, NLog, etc. unless i have no choice.)
2. Is the builder.Services.Add[Logging|ApplicationInsights] stuff even remotely correct? Is it redundant with #1?
3. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to register/inject builder.Configuration so that I can use it *inside* a service. I've been working around things by passing at as parameter to .XDispatch you see (while it technically works i can't imagine that this is the best practice). When the /[snipped] route enters the .XDispatch constructor I'd like to receive it so that methods like .Create can access it. I see all manner of videos (and too much text) that discuss the outside / injection and nothing at all about using / inside the implementation.
4. Same (or similar) notion but with respect to registering / injecting the logger and the surfacing that inside the implementation. Ideas? Further reading?

The builder.Configuration is working but it feels oh so wrong.
When I add the usual "public XDispatch(ILogger logger)" to a service constructor the router becomes very unhappy (it won't even compile unless I stick something in the (lambda parameters) => or similar).

All I want to achieve are the textbook basics:

composing/injecting / *using*

Logging
Config
HttpContext <- this is working fine
CancellationToken <- this is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I was working on a minimal API too and had some similar questions. Googling around I discovered an excellent free Youtube channel by Tim Corey. I suggest that you go there and have a look at his videos about logging in services and APIs it was really helpful and I remember that I solved my issues after that. Hope this will help you too.